# GKE kuberentes uploading yaml file with docker image error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I downloaded a docker image and I am adding that image to the kuberentes yaml file.When I am using the following yaml file

It is giving me the following error :-

kubectl create  -f kubetctl.yaml
error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: found character that cannot start any token

Yaml file below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: autocomplete
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  template:
        spec:
         containers:
             - name:front-end
               image:us.gcr.io/metal-imprint-89503/appengine/default.20170617t172750
               ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Can you format the yaml manifest properly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the last line is improperly indented. It should be a child of `ports:` like this:

```
 containers:
     - name:front-end
       image:us.gcr.io/metal-imprint-89503/appengine/default.20170617t172750
       ports:
           - containerPort: 80
```